# Re-select li not working

Tags: javascript, css

I have a list of `lis`. If an `li` gets selected, it will get a background color of orange, and the previous 'selected' `li's` background color will get removed.

The problem is, if select the same `li` 3 times, nothing happens. The first time, it gets a background color of orange. Second time, the background color will get removed. Third time, the background color should get orange, but it doesn't. Nothing happens.

How can I get the orange color to reappear the third time it gets selected, and have 'normal' behavior every time after?

#### JSFiddle

```js
"use strict"

var parentElem = document.getElementById('wrapper'),
  cells = parentElem.firstElementChild.children,
  previousColorNameSelection = parentElem.children[0];

parentElem.firstElementChild.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  var currentTarget;

  if (e.target.tagName === 'LI') {
    currentTarget = e.target.firstElementChild.firstElementChild;
  } else if (hasClass(e.target, 'namesInnerWrapper')) {
    currentTarget = e.target.firstElementChild;
  } else if (hasClass(e.target, 'namesName')) {
    currentTarget = e.target;
  }
  console.log(currentTarget.innerHTML, currentTarget);

  currentTarget.parentElement.parentElement.style.backgroundColor = 'orange';
  previousColorNameSelection.parentElement.parentElement.style.backgroundColor = '';
  previousColorNameSelection = currentTarget;
});

function hasClass(ele, cls) {
  return ele.className.match(new RegExp('(\\s|^)' + cls + '(\\s|$)'));
}
```

```css
#wrapper {
  width: 300px;
}
li:nth-child(odd) {
  background: rgba(100, 200, 255, 0.1);
}
li {
  list-style-type: none;
}
ul {
  position: relative;
  height: 350px;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <ul>
    <li style="width:100%">
      <div class="namesInnerWrapper"><span class="namesName">balancing</span>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li style="width:100%">
      <div class="namesInnerWrapper"><span class="namesName">preknow</span>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li style="width:100%">
      <div class="namesInnerWrapper"><span class="namesName">barents</span>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li style="width:100%">
      <div class="namesInnerWrapper"><span class="namesName">underwash</span>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li style="width:100%">
      <div class="namesInnerWrapper"><span class="namesName">immaterializing</span>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li style="width:100%">
      <div class="namesInnerWrapper"><span class="namesName">noncreditor</span>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li style="width:100%">
      <div class="namesInnerWrapper"><span class="namesName">unrevised</span>
      </div>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: `previousColorNameSelection = currentTarget` – the problem is, you are doing this on every click, no matter whether it activates or deactivates a LI element. So when a LI is active, you set it as the `previousColorNameSelection` – and then on next click, you set the element’s background to orange, and then remove it straight away again – _because_ `previousColorNameSelection` points to the same LI element already.

Comment: Ah. So how can I fix that?

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to give you an answer in jQuery because it's so much more simple that way. ([JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bsm7hwak/1/))

Let's first just use a class for specifying the background color. Easier to work with.

```
li.active{
  background-color: orange;
}
```

And then let's use jQuery like this:

```js
$(function(){

    $('li').on('click', function(){

        // Save whether or not the li being clicked is already selected
        var alreadySelected = $(this).hasClass('active') ? true : false;

        // Remove the active class from all list items
        $('li').removeClass('active');

        // If it wasn't already selected, then select it now
        if(!alreadySelected) $(this).addClass('active');

    });

});
```

Comment: Thanks! Can you please post a JavaScript answer. Also, the reason I didn't add the event to the `lis`, is because I will have about 150 lis, so I figured it was more efficient adding the event tot he ul